# How is self() used in Pytorch to generate predictions?

Tags: python, pytorch

```
class MNIST_model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, xb):
        xb = xb.reshape(-1, 28 * 28)
        out = self.linear(xb)
        return out
    
    def training_step(self, batch):
        images, labels = batch
        out = self(images)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels)
        return loss
```

I am following the Freecodecamp tutorial.
In the `training_step` method, the tutorial says
`out = self(images)` is used to `Generate Predictions`.

I am not able to understand how is `self` is being used to get the predictions.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually nothing specific to PyTorch but rather to how Python works.
Using parenthesis on an object or directly on *self* inside that class will call a special Python function named [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__). This function is available to your class because you're inheriting from [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html) which implemented it for you.

Here's a minimal example outside of PyTorch:

```
class A():
    def __call__(self):
        print('calling the object')

    def foo(self):
        self()
```

Then

```
>>> x = A()
>>> x.foo() # prints out "calling the object"
```